# Contar número de elementos en un String separados por ';' en SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, split

Estoy intentando hacer una sentencia en SQL que me devuelva un contador de cuántos elementos hay en cada registro separados por ';'. Sería cómo hacer un Split y contar los elementos. No sé muy bien como enfocar esto ya que no sé si existe alguna función Split y cómo hacer para contarlos.

Un ejemplo de lo que estoy intentado hacer es:

```
1 java1;java2;java3 --> 3
2 sql1;sql2 --> 2
3 java1;sql1;sql2 -->
```

Muchas gracias de por adelantado.

Comment: Qué versión de Sql Server usas?

Comment: [Aqui](https://stackoverflow.com/a/738296/579895) tienes una respuesta muy inteligente para resolver el problema.

Comment: Gracias Pikoh !

Comment: @Pikoh no seria bueno traducir esa respuesta?

Comment: @gbianchi pues es posible. Si quieres hacerlo,dale. Si no mañana lo haré yo :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Amigo puedes probar el siguiente query, hice una prueba y me funciono:

```
CREATE TABLE #TEMPTABLA (STRING VARCHAR(MAX));
BEGIN 
    DECLARE @STRING VARCHAR(50) = 'java1;java2;java3',
            @INICIO INT,
            @FIN    INT;
    SELECT @INICIO = 0, @FIN = CHARINDEX(';', @STRING);
    WHILE (@INICIO < LEN(@STRING))
    BEGIN
        INSERT INTO #TEMPTABLA  
        VALUES(REPLACE(SUBSTRING(@STRING, @INICIO, @FIN - @INICIO), ';', ''));
        SET @INICIO = @FIN;
        SET @FIN = @INICIO + CHARINDEX(';', @STRING, @INICIO);
    END
END
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM #TEMPTABLA;
DROP TABLE #TEMPTABLA;
```

Comment: Gracias Victor Perdomo .. a mi también me ha funcionado como esperaba

Answer (score 0):

Podría ser esto:

```
DECLARE @names     VARCHAR(99) = 'java1;java2;java3'
SELECT [elementos] = COUNT(*) FROM STRING_SPLIT(@names,';')
```

O

```
DECLARE @names     VARCHAR(99) = 'java1;java2;java3'
SELECT [elementos] =  (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM STRING_SPLIT(@names,';'))
```

La idea es usar STRING_SPLIT la cual es una función de cadena incorporada; es convertir matrices de cadenas en columnas que están separadas por cualquier separador que quiera definir.

Comment: Tu respuesta podría mejorarse con información de apoyo adicional. Por favor, pulsa en [edit] para añadir más detalles, como citas o documentación, para que otros puedan confirmar que tu respuesta es correcta. Puedes encontrar más información sobre cómo escribir buenas respuestas [en el centro de ayuda](/help/how-to-answer).